# How do I determine all the damaged program image files without running them one by one?

Tags: filesystems, find, io

I have a machine where running various commands results in an `Input/output error`.  This is the result of a hardware fault.

I am trying to determine what files remain undamaged.

My best heuristic so far is that the shell shows the message for *some* files in `/usr/bin` when I try to run them, with most of the files that I have tried so far being fine. I would like to be able to have a *full* list without having to run all the program images in `/usr/bin` one by one.  After all, that is laborious, and might have side effects.

Comment: What?  If you are getting input/output errors there is likely a problem with your machine.  You should check `/var/log/messages` for disk errors.

Comment: @Jesse_b I know.

Comment: @Jesse_b I would not expect to find disk errors in `/var/log/messages` but they are mentioned in the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: depends on the system.  On many systems anything that shows in `dmesg` will also be in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Please! If you have a hardware fault on a disk, stop using it immediately, get another disk of the same or equal size and do a ddrescue of the bad disk onto the new disk immediately or you risk losing it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Using `touch -a /usr/bin/*` will result in a list of only `Input/output error` filenames in `stderr`.

Comment: In a deleted comment, Erik F said that this method would only work if the inode is in a damaged section of the disk: if the actual data is damaged, touch will not suffice.